# Efficient way to transfer money from Greece to Canada

Tags: banking, money-transfer, international-transfer

I currently reside in Canada and I want to transfer a small portion of my money from Greece (from my parents).

What's the most efficient way to transfer money in order to avoid the bank fee + low exchange rate between EU and CAD? IMHO the best way would be to somehow send the money and exchange it in a currency exchange store in Canada, but I am not sure how this is done.

Keep in mind that Greece currently has [capital controls](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Capital_control) but I have the money is both in cash and digital form.

Comment: The international transfer site (usforex) I use says Greece is out of bounds because of those capital controls.  I expect most such sites will be the same. Have you tried something like Western Union? Their website suggests that they operate in Greece, and can probably accept cash easily enough.